# Phone No. is not coming in dropdown on selecting beneficiary through Ajax, its giving error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Phone No. is not coming in dropdown on selecting beneficiary through Ajax, its giving following error

http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/phone_ajax_report.php?benficiary=507

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

```html
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f
; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: beneficiary in C:\wamp\www\sbmpunjab\website_control
\admin_form\phone_ajax_report.php on line <i>4</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align
='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left'
 bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0015</td><td bgcolor
='#eeeeec' align='right'>136064</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\sbmpunjab
\website_control\admin_form\phone_ajax_report.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\phone_ajax_report.php<b>:</b
>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
{"phone_number":"<select name=\"phone_number\"><option value=\"\">Select phone number<\/option>"}
```

**code**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function getXMLHTTP() { //fuction to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }


function getState(districtId) {     

        var strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/constituency_report.php?district="+districtId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {

                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                            $('#Blockdiv').html(returnedData.block);

                      //document.getElementById('GramPanchdiv').innerHTML='<select name="grampanch"><option>Select Gram Panchayat</option></select>';           

                    } else {
                        alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }       
    }

    function getCity(districtId,blockId) {      
        var 
        strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/mis_village_report.php?district="+districtId+"&block="+blockId;

        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {    
      var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);  
       $('#GramPanchdiv').html(returnedData.GramPanch);
      //$('#GramPanchdiv select[name=grampanch]').html(returnedData.GramPanch);

      //document.getElementById('Beneficiarydiv').innerHTML='<select name="beneficiary"><option>Select Beneficiary</option></select>';      
                    } else {
                        alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }

    function getBeneficiary(blockId,villageId) {        

        var strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/beneficiary_ajax_report.php?block="+blockId+"&village="+villageId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {    
                   var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);                 
                    $('#Beneficiarydiv').html(returnedData.beneficiary_name);

                    //$('#Beneficiarydiv select[name=beneficiary_name]').html(returnedData.beneficiary_name);                                       
                    } else {
                        alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }

    function getPhno(benId) {       
        var 
        strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/phone_ajax_report.php?benficiary="+benId;

        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {
      var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);                  
      $('#PhoneNodiv select[name=phone_number]').html(returnedData.phone_number);                                       
                    } else {
                        alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }

    </script>
```

**form**

```
<form method="POST" name="Teleform" id="Teleform" action="<?=DIR_WS_SITE_CONTROL?>index.php?Page=<?=$Page?>&Section=<?=$Section?>&Target=AddTele&TeleID=<?=$TeleID?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this);">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="InsideTable">

        <tr>
          <td align="left" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>Name of TeleCaller</b></td>
          <td align="left" class="InsideRightTd">
            <select name="tele_caller_id" id="tele_caller_id" title="Please select telecaller name.">
                <option>Select Telecaller name</option>
                  <?
                    $DefaultCategory = isset($_POST['id'])?MyStripSlashes($_POST['id']):(isset($CurrentTele->tele_caller_id)?MyStripSlashes($CurrentTele->tele_caller_id):"");
                    $CategoryObj = new DataTable(TABLE_TELE_CALLER_LIST);
                    $CategoryObj->TableSelectAll("","id ASC");
                    while ($CurrentCategory1 = $CategoryObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
                    {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?=$CurrentCategory1->id?>" <?=$DefaultCategory==$CurrentCategory1->id?"selected":""?>><?=$CurrentCategory1->tele_caller_name?></option>
                        <?
                    }
                    ?>
            </select>
         </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td width="20%" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>District</b></td>
                <td class="InsideRightTd">
                  <select name="district" id="district" title="Please select district." onChange="getState(this.value)">
                  <?
                    $DefaultDistrict = isset($_POST['district'])?MyStripSlashes($_POST['district']):(isset($CurrentTele->district_id)?MyStripSlashes($CurrentTele->district_id):DEFINE_DEFAULT_DISTRICT);
                    $DistrictObj = new DataTable(TABLE_DISTRICT);
                    $DistrictObj->TableSelectAll("","district ASC");
                    while ($CurrentDistrict = $DistrictObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
                    {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?=$CurrentDistrict->id?>" <?=$DefaultDistrict==$CurrentDistrict->id?"selected":""?>><?=$CurrentDistrict->district?></option>
                        <?
                    }
                    ?>
                 </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

<?php 
if(isset($CurrentTele->district_id) && $CurrentTele->district_id!='0'){

$BlockObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BLOCKS);
$BlockObj ->Where ="district_id='".$CurrentTele->district_id."'";
$BlockObj->TableSelectAll();
}

?>

            <tr>
                <td width="20%" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>Block</b></td>
                <td class="InsideRightTd">
                <div id="Blockdiv">
                   <? if(isset($CurrentTele->district_id) && $CurrentTele->district_id!='0'){?>
                   <select name="block" onchange="getCity('<?php echo $CurrentTele->district_id; ?>', this.value)" >


            <?while ($CurrentBlock = $BlockObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
            {
        ?>
            <option value="<?=$CurrentBlock->id?>"<?=$CurrentBlock->id==$CurrentTele->block_id ? "selected":""?>> <?=$CurrentBlock->block_name ?></option>
        <?
            }
            ?>      
                </select>
                <?}?>
                <option>Select Block</option>

                 </div>
                </td>
            </tr>


<? if(isset($CurrentTele->district_id) && $CurrentTele->district_id!='0'){

$GramPanchObj = new DataTable(TABLE_GRAM_PANCHAYAT);
$GramPanchObj ->Where ="block_id='".$CurrentTele->block_id."'";
$GramPanchObj->TableSelectAll();
}
?>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>Gram Panchayat</b></td>
                <td class="InsideRightTd">
                <div id="GramPanchdiv">

                <? if(isset($CurrentTele->district_id) && $CurrentTele->district_id!='0'){?>
                <select name="grampanch" onchange="getBeneficiary('<?php echo $CurrentTele->block_id; ?>', this.value)" >

                    <?while ($CurrentGramPanch = $GramPanchObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
                    {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?=$CurrentGramPanch->id?>"<?=$CurrentGramPanch->id==$CurrentTele->village_id ? "selected":""?>> <?=$CurrentGramPanch->village_name ?></option>
                    <?
                    }?>
                    </select>
                <?}?>   
                <option>Select Gram Panchayat</option>

                    </div>
                    </td>
            </tr>

<? if(isset($CurrentTele->village_id) && $CurrentTele->village_id!='0'){

$BeneObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICARY);
$BeneObj ->Where ="village_id='".$CurrentTele->village_id."'";
$BeneObj->TableSelectAll();
}
?>

            <tr>
                <td width="20%" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>Name of Beneficiary</b></td>
                <td class="InsideRightTd">
                <div id="Beneficiarydiv">

                <? if(isset($CurrentTele->beneficiary_name) && $CurrentTele->beneficiary_name!='0'){?>
                <select name="beneficiary_name" onchange="getPhno(this.value)">
                    <?while ($CurrentBene = $BeneObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
                    {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?=$CurrentBene->beneficiary_name?>"<?=$CurrentBene->beneficiary_name==$CurrentTele->beneficiary_name ? "selected":""?>> <?=$CurrentBene->beneficiary_name ?></option>
                    <?
                    }?>
                </select>
                <?}?>   
                <option>Select Beneficiary Name</option>

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

<? if(isset($CurrentTele->village_id) && $CurrentTele->village_id!='0'){

$PhoneObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICARY);
$PhoneObj ->Where ="village_id='".$CurrentTele->village_id."'";
$PhoneObj->TableSelectAll();
}
?>

        <tr>
                <td width="20%" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>Phone No.</b></td>
                <td class="InsideRightTd">
                <div id="PhoneNodiv">

                <select name="phone_number" >
                <? if(isset($CurrentTele->phone_number) && $CurrentTele->phone_number!='0'){

                    while ($CurrentBenePh = $PhoneObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
                    {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?=$CurrentBenePh->phone_number?>"<?=$CurrentBenePh->phone_number==$CurrentTele->phone_number ? "selected":""?>> <?=$CurrentBenePh->phone_number ?></option>
                    <?
                    }

                }?> 
                <option>Select Phone No</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

**phone_ajax_report.php**

```
<?php

$beneficiary=intval($_GET['beneficiary']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','sbmpunjab'); 

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
//mysqli_select_db($con,'sbmpunjab');

$query="SELECT * FROM zsk_beneficiary WHERE id='$beneficiary'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

$phone = '<select name="phone_number"><option value="">Select phone number</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $phone .= "<option value='".$row['phone_number']."'>".$row['phone_number']."</option></select>";
}

$returnArray = array();
$returnArray['phone_number'] = $phone;

echo json_encode($returnArray);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: PLease post your returned JSON as well

Comment: In the string url you are using `strURL="http://localhost//sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/phone_ajax_report.php?**benficiary**="+benId;`
 but in php code using `$beneficiary=intval($_GET['**beneficiary**']);`